# Counter variable i inside variable name

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator

Is it possible to put the counter variable value inside a variable?

I just want to have in the first loop `testData_0_name`, in the second `testData_1_name` etc. Those are my parameters in my records

```
for(var i = 0; i < record.length;i++)
{
    record[i].testData_ **here I want to have  "i"**_name ....
}
```

I don't really want to use any global scopes or something with [window].

Comment: since i is declared inside for loop, it will only affect in that scope

Comment: I don't think you can rename a variable in Java with some iterator or other variables. Maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to say and do. What does "iterator inside a variable" mean for you? What are you actually intending to do here?

Comment: I know, i just want to have in the first loop > testData_0_name, in the second testData_1_name etc. Those are my parameters in my records.

Comment: JAVASCRIPT IS NOT JAVA

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var records = [{'testData_0_name': 0}, {'testData_1_name': 1}, {'testData_2_name': 2}, {'testData_3_name': 3}];

for(var i = 0; i < records.length;i++)
{
    console.log(records[i]['testData_'+i+'_name'])
}
```

You can use bracket notation to access object properties and we can also customize the string in bracket notation like other strings.

Comment: @randomcat This is working for me. Correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks. Only answer that helps me

Comment: glad to help :)